# Getting the 5 most occuring elements in a list with optimal time complexity

Tags: python, time, element, complexity-theory

i'm trying to get the 5 most occurings elements and their count of occurence out of a list. I solved it with a solution that works in time complexity O(5*n*n).

Is there an optimal solution with a better time complexity?

Example Input:

```
[['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646']
 ['16.37.456.153','119.222.123.112','56388','161','17','62','4646']..]
```

Example Output:

```
MostOccurrentElements = [['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646']..]
Counter = [134, ..]
```

With first element of MostOccurrentElements List going with first element of Counter List.

Comment: Post your solution. A sample problem and sample output.

Comment: Use a Counter from the collections library.

Comment: And I think you can get a better complexity with a max heap implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `heapq.nlargest` method to get the 5 most occurring items in O(n log(t)) time complexity, where n is the number of items and t is the number of largest items to get. `collections.Counter` can obtain the counts of each distinct item value in O(n) time, so overall the following code can find the 5 most occurring items in an average of O(n log(t)):

```
from collections import Counter
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
l = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7]
print(heapq.nlargest(5, Counter(l).items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

This outputs:

```
[(3, 4), (4, 4), (6, 3), (1, 2), (5, 2)]
```

Edit: As @jpp points out in the comment, the above can be accomplished with an equivalent wrapper method `most_common` from `Counter`:

```
print(Counter(l).most_common(5))
```

Comment: Ok, can i also get the output like: Elements = [3, 4 , 6, 1, 5] Counter = [4, 4, 3, 2, 2] With the elements 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 being a list of strings itself?

Comment: You can do that with: `elements, counts = zip(*Counter(l).most_common(5))`

Comment: Ok and that also works if i want to get the most occurrent elements of a nested list with strings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a nested list of strings. Can you update your question with examples of this new requirement?

Comment: Ok I updated the question with an example input/output. Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: You should flatten your list of lists first. If your list of lists is stored in variable `l` then you can use `Counter(i for s in l for i in s).most_common(5)`.

Comment: No i dont want to flatten the list. Like ['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'] e.g. is one element out of many. Or what do u mean?

Comment: So e.g., ['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'] is one element and ['16.37.123.155','119.222.456.132','38456','123','17','62','4345'] another.

Comment: In that case I think the existing code `Counter(l).most_common(5)` would already work, since you're simply treating each sublist as one element, right?

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment, but i will test the solution with `elements, counts = zip(*Counter(l).most_common(5))` asap and will give feedback if it worked. Thanks so far :)

Comment: Yeah im treating each sublist as one element, but the function has to check the sublist elements to differentiate between the elements.

Comment: And the `elements, counts = zip(*Counter(l).most_common(5))` solution has the same time complexity like the first solution with a heap queue?

Comment: I get a error message when i use `elements, counts = zip(*Counter(l).most_common(5))` Error Message:`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 477, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 567, in update
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`